# Assigning values inside a foreach loop

Tags: knockout.js

Imagine an array of contacts sorted on name.
This array can be outputted like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: contacts>
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is specify a heading for each li which has a different starting letter, so e.g. displaying A, B, D...

```
- A
- Anderson
- Andrews
- B
- Bellamy
- D
- Davidson
- Davis
```

In normal programming language I would define a variable containing the first letter of the name and check inside the foreach loop to see if it's different. And if this is the case, displaying a header.

How should I do this with knockout.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that sticks to the Knockout patterns. First you'll create a computed observable that maps your array into a new array that's grouped by letter.

```
self.contactsByLetter = ko.computed(function () {
    var result = [],
        currentLetter, currentGroup;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.contacts(), function (contact) {
        if (contact.name[0] !== currentLetter) {
            currentLetter = contact.name[0];
            currentGroup = {
                letter: currentLetter,
                contacts: []
            }
            result.push(currentGroup);
        }
        currentGroup.contacts.push(contact);
    })
    return result;
});
```

Then your HTML will just need two loops.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: contactsByLetter">
    <li class="heading" data-bind="text: letter"></li>
    <!--ko foreach: contacts-->
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    <!--/ko-->
</ul>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/ZcQT4/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the cleaner way, but you could use a fixed array for the letters and then a method on your view model to return only the items starting with the nth letter - i.e.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: letters">
    <li data-bind="text: $data">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: $parent.contactsStartingWith($data)">
             <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

where *contactsStartingWith* could be defined like:

```
function(start) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(contacts(), function(it) { return it.name()[0].toUpperCase() == start } );
}
```

... and the *letters* array can be easily extracted as:

```
viewModel.letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
```

(some useful references for knockout utils working with arrays: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)

Comment: I think Micheal's suggestion is better as it would also avoid having "empty" headers. E.g. if there is no contact with first letter Q. Thanks for reply anyway.

Comment: I agree, and it's also easier to work with (everything is bundled inside an observable) - in fact, i voted for it as well :)